# PWA iOS Splash does not display despite following instructions

Tags: ios, splash-screen, progressive-web-apps

I am making a PWA and I am trying to display splash screen.
I was following this tutorial:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Confirmed with this:

https://www.netguru.co/codestories/few-tips-that-will-make-your-pwa-on-ios-feel-like-native

and my code in my index.html is like this:

```
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">   
 <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="2048x2732" href="splash/apple_splash_2048.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1668x2224" href="splash/apple_splash_1668.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1536x2048" href="splash/apple_splash_1536.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1125x2436" href="splash/apple_splash_1125.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1242x2208" href="splash/apple_splash_1242.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="750x1334" href="splash/apple_splash_750.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="640x1136" href="splash/apple_splash_640.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="2048x1536" href="splash/apple_splash_2048.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="640x960" href="splash/apple_splash_640x960.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="320x480" href="splash/apple_splash_320.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1024x768" href="splash/apple_splash_1024x768.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="2208x1242" href="splash/apple_splash_2208x1242.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1024" href="splash/apple_splash_768x1024.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="2048x1536" href="splash/apple_splash_2048x1536.png"/>
```

This is all in the header of main .html index file, which serves as a template for the whole app. The same way I have done my icon thing, and it works on iOS. The splash version does not (all icons are in the same directory under splash folder). What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,

Grzegorz

Comment: Have you managed to get this working?

Answer (score 7):

***Working answer, as of March 2020***

Instead of manually specifying the individual tags to add the required splash screens and touch icons, the [pwacompat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pwacompat) package (developed by the Google Chrome team), will allow you to easily generate the required assets(splash images and touch icons) for PWA support on iOS devices.

Installation:

```
npm i pwacompat
```

This will ensure that your PWA will be supported even in non-compliant devices/browsers, without the need to manually specify the link tags on your document's `<head>`. More specifically, for the case of Safari, the pwacompat package will do the following:

> - Sets apple-mobile-web-app-capable (opening without a browser chrome)
>     for display modes standalone, fullscreen or minimal-ui
> - Creates
>     apple-touch-icon images, adding the manifest background to transparent
>     icons: otherwise, iOS renders transparency as black
> - Creates dynamic
>     splash images, closely matching the splash images generated for
>     Chromium-based browsers

You may read more about the package on their [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/pwacompat).

Answer (score 7):

Recently bumped into this issue on iOS devices, and figured out there are requirements that your application needs to meet, so:

It is better to include the following meta links on your page's header:

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Your App Name" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
```

Next thing to consider for enabling splash screen for PWA apps on Apple devices (iPads, iPhones, iPod touch) is have a set of `<link ...>` for every existing ***resolution*** and ***orientation*** combination (Obviously, this is apart from those set of icons that are needed to be present in order to make your application PWA enabled).

So:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/12.9__iPad_Pro_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/11__iPad_Pro__10.5__iPad_Pro_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/10.5__iPad_Air_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 810px) and (device-height: 1080px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/10.2__iPad_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/9.7__iPad_Pro__7.9__iPad_mini__9.7__iPad_Air__9.7__iPad_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 428px) and (device-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_13_Pro_Max__iPhone_12_Pro_Max_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 390px) and (device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_13_Pro__iPhone_13__iPhone_12_Pro__iPhone_12_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_13_mini__iPhone_12_mini__iPhone_11_Pro__iPhone_XS__iPhone_X_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_11_Pro_Max__iPhone_XS_Max_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_11__iPhone_XR_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_8_Plus__iPhone_7_Plus__iPhone_6s_Plus__iPhone_6_Plus_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_8__iPhone_7__iPhone_6s__iPhone_6__4.7__iPhone_SE_landscape.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)" href="splash_screens/4__iPhone_SE__iPod_touch_5th_generation_and_later_landscape.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/12.9__iPad_Pro_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/11__iPad_Pro__10.5__iPad_Pro_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/10.5__iPad_Air_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 810px) and (device-height: 1080px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/10.2__iPad_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/9.7__iPad_Pro__7.9__iPad_mini__9.7__iPad_Air__9.7__iPad_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 428px) and (device-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_13_Pro_Max__iPhone_12_Pro_Max_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 390px) and (device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_13_Pro__iPhone_13__iPhone_12_Pro__iPhone_12_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_13_mini__iPhone_12_mini__iPhone_11_Pro__iPhone_XS__iPhone_X_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_11_Pro_Max__iPhone_XS_Max_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_11__iPhone_XR_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_8_Plus__iPhone_7_Plus__iPhone_6s_Plus__iPhone_6_Plus_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/iPhone_8__iPhone_7__iPhone_6s__iPhone_6__4.7__iPhone_SE_portrait.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait)" href="splash_screens/4__iPhone_SE__iPod_touch_5th_generation_and_later_portrait.png">
```

And the ***key point*** that I had to make sure of is the `screen and`  part of the media query for the links (as applied above). I'm not exactly sure if this was needed before, but at the time writing this answer Apple devices (iOS 15.5, iPadOS 15.5) could not resolve the screen side without including `screen` in the media.

Comment: I remember when IE was the bane of every developer's existence.  Now it's iOS.

Answer (score 4):

Right now splash screens are VERY touchy on iOS versions
I was able to make it work ONLY on iOS 11 in the xcode simulator by adding the media attribute.
I do not have a newer iOS device for testing.

Reference article I found here
https://medium.com/@applification/progressive-web-app-splash-screens-80340b45d210

Working example from that article
https://pwa-splash.now.sh

My A2HS tester (a work in progress)
https://a2hs.glitch.me/

Comment: It still did not work on my iPhone 6 with iOS 11.4.1 :( but thank you!

Comment: 2. Did you try adding these that are in the example above your image links? I added them to mine. Not sure if they make a difference.
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#ffffff">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="PWA Splash">

Comment: 1. Are you trying with Safari or Chrome?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working in iPhone XR with Safari + iOS 13.2 :(

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved in iOS 12.1.4! (Splash code is working in my PWA now)

[The release notes don't say much](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209520), but a couple of PWAs I made have their splash screens working again after the update.

Comment: hmm wierd .. still doesn't work on my iphone7 (ios 12.1.4)

Comment: Try https://licitaciones.chilediseno.org and tell me if it works for you. The splash screen file is quite light and the certificate works. The splash screen is a black logo over white background.

Comment: @ganar that link does not work for me, iphone6s (ios 12.2)

Comment: @djolf many thanks for your comment: there was a 403 being generated at that particular set of images. Is working again (I tested it myself on an Iphone 6s)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working in iPhone XR with Safari + iOS 13.2 :(

Comment: Hi @ChristianSaiki: please save https://licitaciones.chilediseno.org as a PWA in your Iphone XR. I just tested  and It works for me on an Iphone 6S running iOS 13.2.3, tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Can also confirm this doesn't work in iOS 13.x.x. Wish I'd seen this sooner

Comment: Hi @PeterB it is working for me in iOS 13.x.x. In order to view the splash screen, you have to make a link of the PWA in the home screen, and open the App from there. Your app has to be hosted on a server that has a valid certificate. 
Test it with  https://licitaciones.chilediseno.org, the splash is a black logo over white background.

Answer (score 0):

Using an [iOS Splash Screen Generator](https://appsco.pe/developer/splash-screens) with following meta tags worked for me:

```
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="YOUR-APP-NAME" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
```