# Splash Screen for iphone in PWA is not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, manifest, splash-screen, progressive-web-apps

I have an issue with splash screen on ios devices. I am using reactjs. I have added all requirements needed for adding splash screen with relevant png file that mentioned here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329040/pwa-ios-splash-does-not-display-despite-following-instructions/53738495#53738495)
[enter link description here](https://a2hs.glitch.me/)

When I am in dev mode (npm start), splash screen is correctly shown and when I click on icon in home screen, relevant splash screen (acc. to device size) is shown before loading page. However, in build mode (npm run build) by clicking on icon in home screen only icon in manifest.json is shown!. I have checked every possible way to find what the problem and nothing achieved unfortunately. Your opinion might help so.

Comment: You can visit this blog post about [Adding Custom iOS Splash Screens To Your Progressive Web App](https://medium.com/appscope/adding-custom-ios-splash-screens-to-your-progressive-web-app-41a9b18bdca3).

**Note:** In fact, it appears to not have worked at all until iOS 11.0.

Comment: I have already seen that post. As I said it works fine in dev mode when I enter npm start and check in ios devices. However, it does not work properly whenever I build app using npm run build. Only icon is shown on screen not "apple-touch-startup-image" I have set before in html. The version of ios in my device is more than 11.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know: This issue has been solved in iOS 12.1.4! (Splash code is working in my PWA now)

[The release notes don't say much](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209520), but a couple of PWAs I made have their splash screens working again after the update.